# Google Sign-In requires iOS SDK 9.0 or above

Tags: swift, ios9, google-signin

I've just updated GoogleSignIn from [CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn), and now I can't build my app.

Error message shown is : 
***Google Sign-In requires iOS SDK 9.0 or above. Please update to the latest Xcode at https://developer.apple.com/xcode/***

However my Xcode version is 7.0.1.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe your project is targeting iOS 8? That could be an interpretation of this message.

Comment: I've already check it but target is iOS 9..